# error show on There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim n As Integer = 0
    str = "select Vote from vote where party='Green'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    if dr.HasRows Then
      dr.Read()
      n = dr("Vote").ToString()
      n = n + 1
      Label8.Text = n.ToString()
    End If

    str = "update Vote set vote='" + n.ToString() + "' where party='Green'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dr.Read()
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Dispose `dr` also at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The message seems to be pretty clear. You have to close the DataReader before trying to use the connection for another operation

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

> While the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is
>   busy serving the SqlDataReader, and no other operations can be
>   performed on the SqlConnection other than closing it. This is the case
>   until the Close method of the SqlDataReader is called. For example,
>   you cannot retrieve output parameters until after you call Close.

```
....
dr.Close()
str = "update Vote set vote='" + n.ToString() + "' where party='Green'"
cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
' ??? dr.Read()
cmd.Dispose()
con.Close()
```

By the way, your whole code could be simplified using an ExecuteScalar to retrieve the last vote value and dumping the DataReader

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim n As Integer = 0
    str = "select Vote from vote where party='Green'"
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
        con.Open()
        Dim n as Integer
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        if result IsNot Nothing Then
            n = Convert.ToInt32(result) + 1
        else
            n = 1
        End If
        Label8.Text = n.ToString()
        str = "update Vote set vote='" + n.ToString() + "' where party='Green'"
        cmd.CommandText = str
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

In this scenario you use a global connection object and this should be avoided. Remember that it is always better to create, open, use and destroy the connection when you need to use it. SqlClient classes could use the [Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) infrastructure that could help a lot in managing precious resources like a connection

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  try

    Dim n As Integer = 0

    str = "select Vote from vote where party='Green'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
    con.Open()

    dr.Close()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    if dr.HasRows Then
      dr.Read()
      n = dr("Vote").ToString()
      n = n + 1
      Label8.Text = n.ToString()
    End If

    str = "update Vote set vote='" + n.ToString() + "' where party='Green'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dr.Read()

   Finally

    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()

  End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple active results set to your connection string as shown below

**Example:**

```
"Server=Server;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```